# Issues compiling XSL file when using `dayTimeDuration` function

Tags: java, xml, xslt, apache-camel, xslt-2.0

I want to offset time zone in XSL but getting errors:

When I use `dayTimeDuration` from namespace `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` I get the following error:

```
Error at xsl:variable on line 11 of :
  XPST0017: XPath syntax error at char 90 on line 11 in {..., xs:dayTimeDuration('PT2H'...}:
    Unknown constructor function: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}dayTimeDuration


javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
```

When I use `xs:dayTimeDuration` form namespace `xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"` I see the error:

```
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
```

How can I offset current time in XSL. Here is the example which is failing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.preadviceevents/functions"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:common="http://www.hermes.co.uk/v2.0.7/common"
                xmlns:pe="http://www.hermes.co.uk/v2.0.7/preadviceEvents"
                xmlns:pct="http://www.hermes.co.uk/v2.0.7/parcelTypes"
                xmlns="http://www.cognitomobile.com/schemas/FieldForceIQ/1.0/TAMS"
                xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs common pe pct fn">

<xsl:variable name="dateNow" select="format-dateTime(adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(current-dateTime(), xdt:dayTimeDuration('PT2H')), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')"/>


<xsl:variable name="dateNow" select="format-dateTime(adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(current-dateTime(), xs('PT2H')), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')"/>
```

I've tried `xdt` and `xs` with no look. What am I missing? Is there a better way of achieving what I want to.

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced from your description: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LUZ

Answer (score 0):

The correct namespace is http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema. The namespace http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes was used for a short time in a draft specification, but never in the final language. You can of course use any prefix that you like so long as you bind it to the right namespace. If you're getting an error with the namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema then we need to see what the error is.

Comment: I've updated description with what errors I am getting

Comment: What Saxon release are you using? I can't reproduce the problem on any recent release. (To find out, use -t on the command line when you process the stylesheet).